# $_POST PDO update : variable variables

Tags: php, pdo

My page receives with $_POST for PDO update:
[image]

```
id: 5296
sg: 5285-5034
t_dur: 133867
...
id_200: data...
id_651: ...
id_38: ...
id_971: ...
id_326: ...
id_327: ...
id_89: ...
```

How to update my table without knowing the id ?

```
UPDATE table_name SET id_XXX = ? AND id_XXX = ? AND ... WHERE id = 5296
```

List of id_*XXX* available in another table.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Consult the manual on the UPDATE syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: If I replace XXX by a number, it works. This is why I ask the question.

Comment: What's with variable variables? If it's received per POST, wouldn't it be an array already? You just need a query builder. -- But more importantly: how did that horrific table scheme come to be?

Comment: NOTE: binding XXX will not work with PDO because you cannot bind column names, only values can be binded. So I hope you have another form of validation in place before entering your column id_XXX numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not secure, but it shows you how to add the columns and values to the query.

```
<?php
$update = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'id_') {
        // Only if $key starts with "id_"
        $update[] = "$key = $value";
    }
}
$sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET ' . implode(", ", $update) . " WHERE id = 10";
```

**[edit]**
Option for null values with ternary operator:

```
<?php
$update = [];
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'id_') {
        // Only if $key starts with "id_"
        $val = (empty($value)) ? 'null' : $value;
        $update[] = "$key = $value";
    }
}
$sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET ' . implode(", ", $update) . " WHERE id = 10";
```

**[/edit]**

Comment: It works ! Thanks, but how to set "null" $value if empty ? (exemple : id_89 = '' -> id_89 = _null_)